# headerfile not found

Tags: ios, xcode, import, header-files

I am working on a iphone app and everything went fine untill I tried to import NSFetchedResultsController.h. when I was typing this Xcode completed it for me. But now it gives the error: NSFetchedResultsController.h file not found.

I included it like this:

```
#import "NSFetchedResultsController.h"
```

I looked all over the internet for the answer to this, but nothing works. (and a few things need Xcode 4.3 to work).

I am using Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I expect you tired already cleaning the project and closing XCode.

Comment: Yes, and the error was gone then, until I tried to run the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you really don't need to import the header manually in most cases. 
just add Coredata.framework to build phases as below:

[image]

[image]

Now look at left in project navigator, you see CoreData.framework added. open Header folder and simply you can find NSFetchedResultsController.h.
For testing its existence, you can type:

> CoreData/NSFet

and voila, code suggestion tells you what you wanted . look at the picture below:

[image]

IMPORTANT: this is available only for iOS 3 or higher

Comment: Just some notes: 1. Autocompletion on "#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>" works also before the CoreData framework has been added. - 2. "#import <CoreData/NSFetchedResultsController.h>" is *not necessary* because it is already included by <CoreData/CoreData.h>. - So I do not see a big difference to my answer (apart from the pictures).

Comment: That's right 'Martin R". At the top of discussion I said that it is not necessary to import the header manually.

Comment: ok, it worked. I had already added the CoreData package, but when importing I didn't put the CoreData/ before the NSFetchedResultsController.h

Answer (score 4):

"NSFetchedResultsController.h" is part of the CoreData framework, you have to

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

You also have to add the CoreData framework to the libraries that your app is linked with:

- Select your target in Xcode.
- Click on "Build Phases".
- In the "Link Binary With Libraries" section, click on "+" and add "CoreData.framework".

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this discussion is very basic for advanced programmers, but it may be useful for advanced programmers who have recently moved to Cocoa, or for beginners in Cocoa/Xcode. This may worth to have a look.

When you want to add a new header which is not included by default , you can first search google for that class reference in Apple Developer ( you can do that directly from your Xcode > Organizer ( at right top of Xcode window )
You should see a page like this:

[image]

Two most important things are : 1- Framework 2- Inherits From and
Then check the framework in your Build Phases> Link Binary With Libraries  and add it if not exist.
By This , you should never encounter such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file is exist in the project folder, if yes, go to the project, select the app under targets section, go to build phases, open compile source then add the file `NSFetchedResultsController.m`.

Comment: Where can i find the NSFetchedResultsController.m? I already tried finding it by searching the whole mac, but it only finds NSFetchedResultsController.h?