# need to fix error in code "Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type 'id'."

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im writing this code for my class and I'm stuck, the error is "Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type 'id'

it falls on this line of code:

```
if (![self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save:&error])
```

I understand that earlier in the code I am setting newDetailItem to type id?  :

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }        
}
```

here is the full code i have going right now:

```
#import "cavDetailViewController.h"


@interface cavDetailViewController ()
<UIAlertViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    UIAlertView *message;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation cavDetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }        
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id) sender
{
    [self.lattitude resignFirstResponder];
    [self.longitude resignFirstResponder];
    [self.description resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) pAnimated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:pAnimated];

    [self.detailItem setValue:self.lattitude.text    forKey:@"Lattitude"];
    [self.detailItem setValue:self.longitude.text    forKey:@"Longitude"];
    [self.detailItem setValue:self.description.text    forKey:@"Description"];

    NSNumber * v = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.lattitude.text doubleValue]];
    NSNumber * v1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.longitude.text doubleValue]];


    [self.detailItem setValue:v forKey:@"Lattitude"];
    [self.detailItem setValue:v1 forKey:@"Longitude"];

    // ND: do the update - ala master view code
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
        // You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }


} // end method veiwWillDisappear

#pragma mark - Split view

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}

- (IBAction)bgroundColor:(id)sender
{
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor] ];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] ];    

}



- (IBAction)dispMessage:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Have a nice day"
                                                      message:@"Have a nice day"
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `detailItem` property is declared with the type of `id`. You should do one of the following:

- Declare it with a type that exposes the `managedObjectContext` property, or
- Add a type cast of `self.detailItem` to a class exposing the `managedObjectContext` property, or
- Change the syntax to call `managedObjectContext` as a method

The last change can be done like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self.detailItem managedObjectContext] save:&error])
```

In order for this to work, your .m file needs to include the header for the class that exposes the `managedObjectContext` property.

Comment: please elaborate on the .m file (which is what i had posted, not the .h file) about the header for the class comment you had made, please. In the .h file i did set the property as such:  @property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

Comment: im looking and i cant find it im getting so frustrated with this, ive got more to write but cant move on until this part is fixed.....I have the DetailViewController.m file which is what this file is, I have the MasetrViewController file, and the .h  file for both of these files.  I know I must be really frustrating as a new programmer....

Comment: I did a "Find in Project" search and it only came up with 2 references for setDetailItem, one of which is:-(void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem , which is in the DetailViewController.m file,

Comment: the other is in the MasterViewController.m for a segue:- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

Comment: @BrentSchulze So it's `NSManagedObject` then! You need to add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to your .m file ([make sure that coredata framework is added to your project, too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12484182/335858)). Optionally you can add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to the header of your view controller, and replace `id` in the declaration of `detailItem` with `NSManagedObject*`. This would let you use the property directly the way you wrote in your post.

Comment: AHHHH that makes sense, i ran across a few articles on CoreData when i searched for his error, but none of them indicated i needed to add that to the header file. Made the changes and it runs, but wont save the data

Comment: i enter a longitute, and a lattitude, and select the "Master" button to go back to the master view, and it "crashes" the program

Comment: @BrentSchulze You need to step through your code in a debugger then. If you get a stack trace, you may want to post it in a separate question: at this point, this is a different problem than what your post describes.

Comment: actually it crashes if i select the master button even if i dont enter newDetail data in the fields

Comment: by crash i mean it exits to the home screen, and i guess yes that means i should start over with a new set of questions, thanks for your time